# How to close a python figure by keyboard input?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm  trying to write a python program that displays a figure for indefinite time and closes it after any keyboard key is pressed.

In fact, the python program should do the same as this Matlab code:

```
t = 0:0.01:2;
s = sin(2 * pi * t);

plot(t,s)

pause
close
```

In python I'm able to plot the figure but nothing happens after the keyboard input.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

#plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,s)
#plt.show()
plt.draw()

raw_input("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE.")
plt.close(fig)
```

So far I observed that `plt.close(fig)` does not do anything in conjunction with `plt.show()`. However, when I use `plt.draw()` instead, `plt.close(fig)` is closing the figure. Yet, when I add `raw_input("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE.")` into my program, the figure does not appear at all.

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried experimenting with `plt.ion()`, but without success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

something like this maybe ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)


fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,s)
#plt.show()
plt.draw()
plt.pause(1) # <-------
raw_input("<Hit Enter To Close>")
plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: @BorisL. then please consider marking Joran's solution as "the answer".

Comment: @JoranBeasley, the plot window pops up at background. I need to use my mouse to click and view the plot. Can't the plot come to the front and just by pressing `Enter` or `q` I can close it (like the way we do for gnuplot)?

Answer (score 22):

I think that using `plt.waitforbuttonpress(0)` could solve the trick of using `raw_input()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,s)
plt.draw()
plt.waitforbuttonpress(0) # this will wait for indefinite time
plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: this works if we have some non-zero number for time: `plt.waitforbuttonpress(1)`.
with zero, it just keeps on waiting.. and doesn't work..

what works for me is this: 

`plt.waitforbuttonpress(1); input(); plt.close(fig)`

Answer (score 1):

As of writing (December 2021, using Matplotlib 3.5 on Windows), pressing the `q` key now seems to close a figure by default – at least with the Tk and Qt GUI backends that I tried. If another *specific* key is desired instead, e.g. the `escape` key, one might want to follow the solution provided in [this discussion](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/830/), which uses event handling:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def close_figure(event):
    if event.key == 'escape':
        plt.close(event.canvas.figure)

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

plt.plot(t, s)
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', close_figure)
plt.show()
```